# Is there a CDN version of Emotion lib?

Tags: emotion

I'm trying to use Emotion lib in a legacy angular 1.x version code where import statements are not supported. I'm not able to find a way to use Emotion other than using import as they have not documented any other way. So I was thinking if I could use some CDN version of the library, then that would be easy to be used in Angular code. But I haven't found so far any CDN link for it that works. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Found out by asking the same question on Emotion's slack channel. Here's the [React version](https://unpkg.com/@emotion/core@10.0.15/dist/core.umd.min.js) of it and this is the [framework agnostic version](https://unpkg.com/emotion@10.0.23/dist/emotion.umd.min.js)

The first one exposes an `emotionCore` object and the second one `emotion` object.